# How to show that the limit of $f(n) \rightarrow 0$ in $n\rightarrow \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I am trying to find a way to show that the following expression goes to $0$ in $n\rightarrow \infty$:

$$
f(n)  = \frac{\frac{(n-d)(n-1)}{n}-\frac{(n-d)(n-1)}{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{e_i}}}{n(n-1) - \sum_{i=1}^n e_i (n-1)} 
  = \frac{(n-d)\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{e_i}}\right)}{n-\sum_{i=1}^n e_i}.
$$

where $d$ is some finite integer constant, $n\in \mathbb Z$, $n>d>0$ and $ 1> e_1\geq e_2\geq ...\geq e_n\geq \frac{1}{n-1}$.

I am not sure how to deal with infinite sums in this problem as I don't think that they converge (?).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One problem I can see right off the bat is that if $e_i=1$ for all $i$ (which is possible given your conditions), then you wind up with $f(n)$ is undefined for all $n$ (it is zero divided by zero). So, there would not be any limit. You need to ensure the function actually exists by imposing some additional restrictions on the $e_i$'s.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In my expression, some share of "e"'s is supposed to be always $<1$. I will fix it in the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the Harmonic Mean:
$$HM(e_1,\ldots,e_n) = \dfrac{n}{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{e_i}}$$

and the Arithmetic Mean:
$$AM(e_1,\ldots, e_n) = \dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n e_i}{n}$$

You have:

$$\begin{align*}f(n) & = \dfrac{(n-d)\left(\dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{e_i}}\right)}{\displaystyle n-\sum_{i=1}^n e_i} \\ & = \left(\dfrac{n-d}{n^2}\right)\left(\dfrac{1-HM(e_1,\ldots,e_n)}{1-AM(e_1,\ldots,e_n)}\right)\end{align*}$$

For the term on the right, let's look for an upper bound for the numerator and a lower bound for the denominator.

$$1-HM(e_1,\ldots,e_n) \le 1-\min(e_1,\ldots,e_n) = 1-e_n < 1 \\ 1-AM(e_1,\ldots,e_n) \ge 1-\max(e_1,\ldots,e_n) = 1-e_1$$

Thus, $$0 \le f(n) \le \left(\dfrac{n-d}{n^2}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{1-e_1}\right)$$

And so by the Squeeze theorem, the limit as $n \to \infty$ is $0$. QED.

Based on your comment above, it sounds like some of the $e_i$'s might be equal to one, but you know there exists some $e_i<1$. If that is the case, then the argument changes slightly. There must exist $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\ge N$,

$$AM(e_1,\ldots, e_n) \le AM(e_1,\ldots, e_N) < 1 \\ \Longrightarrow 1-AM(e_1,\ldots, e_n) \ge 1-AM(e_1,\ldots, e_N) > 0$$

And then the proof follows just the same. You just need a constant, so since the $e_i$'s are nonincreasing, you just need a fixed number of them, and the arithmetic mean of those will be constant.

Comment: Thank you! I will research the Squeeze Theorem in-depth, but it seems that this method should work.

Comment: I have one more question with regards to the proposed approach. It seems like if we consider $f$ to be the function of $\vec{e}$, it is neither convex nor concave (it is Indeterminate over $\vec{e}$. Therefore, it might be the case that the function attains its maximum for some intermediate values of $e_i$ and $f(n)$ might have a different upper boundary. Can we still use the Squeeze Theorem in this case?

Comment: I have done a quick check in Mathematica. The function is indeed indetermined over $\vec{e}$. Observe that both nominator and denominator increase in $e_i$, having an ambiguous overall effect on the function. I think that your hinge about the function being bound by those two bounds is still correct, but I am not sure whether there is a feasible way to show that it is indeed true.

Comment: I have tried this one too. Unfortunately, it does not change much.

Comment: Thank you, I will check it

Comment: I have tried to find the boundaries once more time but bumped into the same problem (that is the function being indeterminate even after suggested simplification).  I see that the sums have cyclic nature, but I am not sure how to leverage this. Is there something obvious I am not seeing? P.S. Also, I am sorry for a delayed response.

Comment: @Oleh I figured it out and cleaned up my answer significantly.

Comment: this looks like an elegant solution. Thank you!